# Selecting table inside database structure

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using Xampp localhost. How can I select the database inside the database structure? here is my code.

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=lifeands_phdb_150522", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //echo "Connected successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

I want to select database name loan_calculator. Here is the picture of the database. [image]

Any one can help?

Comment: your database is lifeands_phdb_150522 and you already put it. loan_calculator is a table inside lifeands_phdb_150522  databse. so you have to use your table name inside your query.

Comment: `How can I select the database inside the database structure?` Do you want select loan_calculator? It's a table though.

Comment: Yes, I want to select the loan_calculator.  I had try to select it using select table but itd doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fetch from the table "loan_calculator" of "lifeands_phdb_150522" DB. select the DB and write the query to fetch data from table

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=lifeands_phdb_150522", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

//to query table   
$sql = 'SELECT *  FROM loan_calculator'; 
$res = $conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply try this

```
    if (!$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
      echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
      exit;
    }

   if (!mysql_select_db('lifeands_phdb_150522', $link)) {
      echo 'Could not select database';
      exit;
   }

   $sql    = 'SELECT *  FROM loan_calculator';
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. to suggest this one to someone who uses PDO is not a good idea. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php